# Angular routing with parameters doesn't work when URL is requested out of the app

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing

I have a problem with Angular routing, the app fails if a URL with a parameter is requested from out of the app.

http://localhost:4200/clients
This route works if you navigate to it from the app or just typed it in the address bar.

http://localhost:4200/clients/20 
This route works if you navigate to it from the app and **NOT** working if typed in the address bar.

**Note**: In the console, it requests the css and javascript files from the second level route (http://localhost:4200/clients/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js instead of http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js)

Any help?

Comment: Is this an angularjs or Angular app. You should perhaps show some code of your routing configurations.

Comment: "doesn't work" can mean a lot of things. What is happening when you do that? is it completely failing, is the root page requested or is it resulting in a 404 error?

Comment: Well, it fails at the very beginning while loading the resources of the page, as the path of all resources is changed as i referred to in the note at the end of the question.

Comment: can i ask how you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is done by enabling using the hash in the routing.

In app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'ImportOperations', component: ImportOperationComponent },
        { path: 'ImportData/:Id', component: ImportRawDataComponent },
        { path: 'rules/:Id', component: RulesComponent },
        { path: 'newrule', component: RulesComponent },
        { path: 'rules', component: RulesListComponent },
        { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },        
        { path: 'editresult/:Id', component: EditSearchComponent }
      ]
      ,{useHash: true}),
```